# Issue with libreadline when completing an upper case directory

Tags: c, shell, readline

this is a piece of a shell that I'm creating. I'm having some trouble using libreadline, because when the shell gets loaded and I try to cd in a directory using autocompletion (so pressing TAB), after I press enter I access the directory but I get some strange output before another prompt is printed. I noticed that this happens only when the name of the directory starts with an upper case letter.

Example: "user:: ~ % cd Github"   <-- written pressing tab to autocomplete Github

Next prompt is: "8b�/�user :: Github %"
I really cannot understand why, this is something really strange for me.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include "flush.h"
#include "env.h"
#include "fget.h"

char * flush_builtins[] =
{
  "cd",
  "help",
  "exit",
  "ver",
  "fget"
};

int flush_num_builtins() {
  return sizeof(flush_builtins) / sizeof(char *);
}

int (*flush_func[]) (char **) =
{
  &flush_cd,
  &help,
  &exit_flush,
  &ver,
  &fget
};

static int flush_startp(char **args)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "flush: command not found\n");
    }
    exit(1);
  }
  else if (pid < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "flush: command not found\n");
  }
  else
  {
    do
    {
      waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
  }

  return 1;
}

static int flush_exec(char **args)
{
  int i;

  if (args[0] == NULL)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < flush_num_builtins(); i++)
  {
    if (strcmp(args[0], flush_builtins[i]) == 0) {
      return (*flush_func[i])(args);
    }
  }

  return flush_startp(args);
}

static char * flush_read(void)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  char *line_read = malloc(sizeof(char) * LINE_BUF);
  char *prompt = malloc(sizeof(char) * LINE_BUF);
  char *current, buffer[TOK_BUF];
  current = getcwd(buffer, TOK_BUF);

  strcat(prompt, get_user());
  strcat(prompt, " :: ");

  if (strcmp(current, get_home()) == 0)
  {
    strcat(prompt, "~");
  }

  else
  {
    strcat(prompt, get_cwd());
  }

  strcat(prompt, " % ");
  line_read = readline(prompt);

  if (line_read && *line_read)
  {
    add_history(line_read);
  }

  return line_read;
  free(prompt);
  free(line_read);
  free(current);
}

static char **flush_getargs(char * line)
{
  int bufsize = TOK_BUF;
  int i = 0;
  char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char *));
  char **token;

  if (!tokens)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  token = strtok(line, DELIM);
  while (token != NULL)
  {
    tokens[i] = token;
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
  }

  tokens[i] = NULL;
  return tokens;
}


static void flush_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int  status;

  do
  {
    line = flush_read();
    args = flush_getargs(line);
    status = flush_exec(args);
    free(line);
    free(args);
  } while (status);
}

static void handler(int num)
{
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
  flush_loop();
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main()
{
  init();
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
  flush_loop();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `strcat` with a non `\0` terminated string:

```
char *prompt = malloc(sizeof(char) * LINE_BUF);
char *current, buffer[TOK_BUF];
current = getcwd(buffer, TOK_BUF);

strcat(prompt, get_user());
```

Use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`, or `calloc` instead of `malloc`